# What's wrong with this syntax of parameterized INSERT query?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, ms-access-2007, xlrd, comtypes

I'm trying to import excel data into MS-access database, but it's giving me 'Syntax Error Definition'

Code:

```
for col_index in range(0,work_sheet.ncols):
    column_value = work_sheet.cell(0,col_index).value
    for row_index in range(1, work_sheet.nrows):
        row_value = work_sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value # For the same column, fetch the row data repeatedly
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO my_table" [column_value] "VALUES(" & row_value & ")")
```

Error:

```
C:\Data\Database>c:\python27\python.exe My_First_DB_Code.py
File "My_First_DB_Code.py", line 32
db.Execute("INSERT INTO my_table" [column_value] "VALUES(" & row_value & ")")

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note: I have already imported the column names from the excel sheet and now trying to import the row values, column by column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Python's string concatenation syntax, not SQL's. Try generating the SQL string separately, then printing it to make sure it's correct before making the DB call:

```
query_string = "INSERT INTO my_table" + str(column_value) + " VALUES( " + str(row_value) + " )"
print(query_string)
# db.Execute(query_string)
# uncomment when you know the query is correct
```

The above code assumes that you want to concatenate `my_table` and `column_value` with no spaces between them. If, as HansUp [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824852/whats-wrong-with-this-syntax-of-parameterized-insert-query/27825101?noredirect=1#comment44057319_27825101), you are trying to input into a field name, set `query_string` like so:

```
query_string = query_string = "INSERT INTO my_table ([" + str(column_value) + "]) VALUES ('" + str(row_value) + "')"
```

Comment: No, still gives the Syntax error `_ctypes.COMError: (-2146825154, None, (u'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'
, u'DAO.Database', u'jeterr40.chm', 5003134, None))`

Comment: @manty try generating the query string first, then print it to make sure it's what you're trying to achieve. See my edit above.

Comment: I thought *column_value* is the name of the field which is to receive the inserted value.  If so, you must include parentheses around the target field name in the finished statement: `INSERT INTO my_table ([field name]) VALUES (...`

Comment: @HansUp thanks, I don't use SQL that often, and it's kind of unclear what the OP wants as the query string. I'll update my answer with your input.

Comment: @HansUp I put both options in the answer. Hopefully one will work.

Comment: @MattDMo I understand what you are trying to say here, but as far as I know, SQL and Python doesn't work as simple as "subprocess.call(command)". Also your suggested approach is not working here. e.g. check out this answer where Gord has given a different approach : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786531/data-type-conversion-error-while-trying-to-dynamically-add-columnsfields-from/27786886#27786886) I'm looking for a somewhat similar approach but unable to do so.

Comment: @manty can you give a concrete example of the query you're trying to generate? For example, give some actual values of `column_value` and `row_value`, then give the full query string you'd like to generate using those values. Also, what are the results of `print(type(column_value))` and `print(type(row_value))`? Please edit your question to include all of this, then leave me a comment when you're ready. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes we can be so wrong in our understanding w.r.t to my comment above. Your method actually just worked. It was just the matter of some spaces in the query. Please update the 2nd option of your answer with this code and I'll accept it as the answer. `query_string = "INSERT INTO DIRS ([" + str(column_value) + "]) VALUES ('" + str(row_value) + "')"`. Your above comment actually helped i.e. of giving a concrete example.